# Uso do WaitAll em C#

Tags: c#, thread, multithreading

Tenho o seguinte problema:

Um programa gera dois tipos de threads A e B através de cliques em seus respectivos botões. Os dois tipos não podem executar ao mesmo tempo. Se eu tiver 10 threads A, a B só pode executar quando as 10 do tipo A terminarem.

Consigo restringir a entrada,  criando um mutex para cada tipo e uma variável booleana que me diz se existe ou não threads do outro tipo sendo executadas. Porém, quando termina a primeira thread, a do tipo contrário pode entrar na região crítica porque estou usando nomeMutex.WaitOne().

Como posso adaptar o uso do 'WaitAll' para esta situação? Não consegui compreender bem o conceito.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

É possível resolver esse problema usando:

- um `Mutex` (`lock`)
- dois contadores, um para A e outro para B
- e dois eventos de reset manual [`ManualResetEventSlim`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.threading.manualreseteventslim%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

  O `ManualResetEventSlim` serve para travar a execução quando alcança o método `Wait`, mas somente se estiver em estado *`não-setado`* (existem dois estados, *`setado`* e *`não-setado`*). Threads podem chamar o método `Set` para colocar o objeto em estado *`setado`*, ou `Reset` para colocar em estado *`não-setado`*.
- exemplo: uma implementação fácil, seria como abaixo. Este código entretanto não cuida de casos e *starvation*, que é quando As ou Bs podem ser impedidos de executar, caso a thread do tipo oposto entre com mais frequência do que o processador é capaz de executá-las... assim sendo o número de threads do tipo oposto só aumenta.

  ```
  private static int a = 0;
  private static int b = 0;
  private static readonly object locker = new object();
  private static readonly ManualResetEventSlim mreA = new ManualResetEventSlim(true);
  private static readonly ManualResetEventSlim mreB = new ManualResetEventSlim(true);

  static void A()
  {
      while (true)
      {
          lock (locker)
          {
              // se não tem Bs executando, então o A pode executar
              if (b == 0)
              {
                  // o A vai executar, então devemos:
                  //  - impedir o acesso de Bs
                  //  - incrementar o contador de As
                  mreB.Reset();
                  a++;
                  break;
              }
          }

          // já tem Bs executando, vamos ficar esperando um sinal para continuar A
          mreA.Wait();
      }

      Console.WriteLine("A está executando");

      lock (locker)
      {
          // o A terminou, então:
          //  - decrementamos o contador de As
          //  - liberamos os Bs, se não houver mais As executando
          a--;
          if (a == 0)
              mreB.Set();
      }
  }

  static void B()
  {
      while (true)
      {
          lock (locker)
          {
              // se não tem As executando, então o B pode executar
              if (a == 0)
              {
                  // o B vai executar, então devemos:
                  //  - impedir o acesso de As
                  //  - incrementar o contador de Bs
                  mreA.Reset();
                  b++;
                  break;
              }
          }

          // já tem As executando, vamos ficar esperando um sinal para continuar B
          mreB.Wait();
      }

      Console.WriteLine("B está executando");

      lock (locker)
      {
          // o B terminou, então:
          //  - decrementamos o contador de Bs
          //  - liberamos os As, se não houver mais Bs executando
          b--;
          if (b == 0)
              mreA.Set();
      }
  }
  ```

<sub>Resposta anterior</sub>

**ReaderWriterLockSlim**

O que são A e B? Me parece o caso de um [reader-writer lock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers%E2%80%93writer_lock), onde a leitura pode ser executada várias vezes ao mesmo tempo, e a escrita pode ser executada apenas se nada mais estiver executando, nem outras escritas nem leituras sendo feitas.

Se for este o caso, o melhor é usar um [`ReaderWriterLockSlim`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim(v=vs.110).aspx), que faz parte do framework .Net, que serve exatamente para isso.

Comment: Na verdade, meu problema se parece mais com o do "Banheiro Unissex". Poderia dizer que A e B são homens e mulheres tentando usar o mesmo "banheiro". Se tiver A, só A pode entrar e B espera esvaziar. Se tiver B, só B pode entrar e A espera esvaziar.

Comment: Entendo... nesse caso o `ReaderWriterLockSlim` não serve realmente. Fiz uma implementação usando um Mutex, dois `ManualResetEventSlim` e dois contadores. Não é perfeita (sofre de starvation), mas é um bom início. Vê ai se te serve, e me fala se tiver dúvida.